# Create google map tiles with php

Tags: php, google-maps, png

So I'm looking to create something like google maps traffic layer

As far as I know they create .png tiles on the server and then overlay them on the map.

That is exactly what I want to do. Create .png tiles and overlay them on the map. I just don't know how I would go about programming (preferably php) to create those .png tiles.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good first step to learning how to programmatically create png files in php: 
http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml

Essentially you are going to be dealing with a lot of PHPs, GD and Image functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Good luck.

You will then want to position them on top of each other using CSS position attributes.

Comment: Not CSS position attributes. Instead You create the .png files with an adequate name scheme and you pass the URL to the ImageMapType object and the API takes care of positioning them correctly. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ImageMapType and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ImageMapTypeOptions